# Avoiding Netbeans documentation pop up window when editing code

Tags: netbeans

This info window you see down here appears every time some CSS property or HTML attribute is written. The one on the top contains documentation about that element, and I dont want it to appear as it is very annoying when coding.

How can I make it not appearing? I've searched on Tools - Hints but cant fins this option.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Tools->Options->Code Completion tab

Remove checkbox from "Auto popup documentation window"

Comment: Netbeans 8.1: Tools -> Options -> *Editor* -> Code Completion -> Auto popup documentation window

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans 8.2

> Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion -> Auto popup documentation window

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me today.

Answer (score 2):

Click on `Tools--->Java Platforms`.

`Classes` tab will be open by default,please switch it to `Javadoc` tab!

[image: NetBeans IDE]

There will be a manual entry for javadoc like `http:\\docs.oracle.com/java/api/...`,kindly click on Remove button,close this window and then restart Netbeans IDE!!!

This effect will be done and you won't be seeing any popups!

If it doesn't help,please leave a comment!

Comment: Thank! I am afraid no Java Platforms option is on my version, I forgot to mention Im on IDE 7.4: http://i.imgur.com/uDkp6ru.png

Comment: I looked at them, there is a JAVA tab but no Classes in there at all: http://i.imgur.com/f8U1sU6.png

Comment: Also looked on Hints tab but nothing in there also I am afraid: http://i.imgur.com/12yIFXm.png

Comment: I told to go under `Tools` option in Menu Bar!

Comment: Yes, both screenshots are taken from MENU - TOOLS - OPTIONS. On the Tools menu theres no java option: http://i.imgur.com/uDkp6ru.png

Comment: I think I'll upgrade to version 8

Comment: Best option and also,please save all the contents of your open project! Then,try the same as I hinted! If not found,I'll suggest you updating OR some other option but I don't have Netbeans 7.4 RIGHT NOW! SO,please mention what step you're taing first! But,please try my second suggestion related to closing and then trying the same options!